# Downgrading Windows 8 Home Premium to Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, downgrade, anytime-upgrade

Someone generously donated a Windows 8 laptop to the organization I work for, however we just (finally) standardized on a single OS -- Windows 7. I would like to downgrade to Windows 7, but the OS that came with the system was Windows 8 Home Premium, not Pro. If I use Windows Anytime Upgrade to move to Pro, will it then let me downgrade to Windows 7 Pro? Is there another cost effective way to dump Windows 8 for Windows 7 Home Premium or Pro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [Microsoft Web Site](http://www.microsoft.com/oem/en/licensing/sblicensing/pages/downgrade_rights.aspx):

> The following OEM versions of Windows software are eligible for
>   downgrade rights.
>   Windows 8 Pro includes downgrade rights to:
>    - Windows 7 Professional
>    - Windows Vista Business

So to answer your question, no you cannot downgrade directly from Windows 8 Home Premium. If you were to upgrade from Home Premium to Pro you would downgrade back to Win7 Pro using the following steps (also from the Microsoft website):

> The downgrade process   Follow these steps to downgrade to a previous
>   version of Windows software:
>
> Obtain genuine Windows media and a corresponding product key for the
>   version of Windows that is eligible for downgrade.
>    - The media should come from a prior legally licensed version from the    OEM or retail channels.
>    - Qualified OEMs have the option to distribute downgrade media and    product keys directly to end users, per end user request.
>    - End users who are licensed separately through Microsoft Volume    Licensing (VL) may provide their VL media and key to a system builder 
>   to facilitate the downgrade on their own systems.
>
> Insert the downgrade-eligible version of Windows media in the CD drive
>   and follow the installation instructions.
>
> Type the product key.
>
> - If the software was previously activated, you will not be able to    activate it online. In this case, the appropriate local Activation
>     Support phone number will be displayed. Call the number and explain
>     the circumstances. When it is determined that the end user has an
>     eligible Windows license, the customer service representative will
>     provide a single-use activation code to activate the software. Please 
>     note that Microsoft does not provide a full product key in this
>     scenario.
>
> Activate the software.

Depending on your licensing arrangement, you may be able to obtain a Windows 7 Pro key for much cheaper than buying a Win 8 Pro key. Verify this before attempting to proceed. If you really are standardized, I would assume you would have a volume license agreement with Microsoft.

Comment: Thanks. It sounds like an Anytime upgrade to Win 8 Pro wouldn't help much, alas. Unfortunately, while we have a Software Assurance agreement for Office, we don't for Windows. We obtained a great deal on refurbished systems last year with Windows 7 on them, which allowed us to skip those licenses.